# How do jQuery do its cross-domain ajax calls and how can I replicate em with mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools, cross-domain

in my eternal internal fight on whether to stay with mootools or jump to jQuery I've found on the jQuery documentation something that got my attention and this is that jQuery can ask for a JSON to a different domain, which is usually forbidden by the browser.

I've seen some workarounds for cross-subdomain, but never cross-domain, and I'm really thrilled, first I thought I was server related but experimenting a little bit more I've seend that doing the very same JSON request from jQuery docs on Mootools doesn't work!

This works
jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });
```

This doesn't
Mootools:

```
var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?", onComplete: function(person, responseText){
    alert(responseText);
}}).get({});
```

How can I replicate this behavior ? what causes it ?

jQuery Doc: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback
Mootols Doc: http://mootools.net/docs/Request/Request.JSON

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's said right on the page that it's JSONP.

JSONP is a trick where the server, instead of returning the usual response, wraps it into a method call of the user-supplied method, e.g. instead of:

`{"foo": "bar", "baz":"bah"}`

It would return:

`temporaryCallbackFunctionName({"foo": "bar", "baz":"bah"});`

jQuery defines the temporary callback function and inserts a `<script src="..."></script>` element, which is not limited by the same origin policy.

When the script is loaded, the function is executed and that's it.

The downside is that if the server is evil (or hacked) it can now execute arbitrary code in your browser.

More info [here](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/).

Comment: I just read that, it brilliant ! the only problem would be the prepending :P

Answer (score 3):

You may use JSONP in MooTools by using a plugin, [JSONP](http://www.clientcide.com/docs/Request/JsonP). It's made by [Aaron Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10071/anutron), one of the core MooTools developers.

Answer (score 1):

This is included in MooTools more since v1.2.2 (released on April 23rd 2009).

Check [this documentation page](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.JSONP) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't do it with Mootools, according to its API docs and [this forum](http://forum.mootools.net/topic.php?id=4155).

The reason this is limited is probably because of [Cross-site scripting attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).