# Problems when calling $.Ajax in Firefox and Chrome in a cross domain call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, firefox, google-chrome

I have some asmx web services in an url (ie. example.com/Entities/WebServices supposing example.com is my domain). The aim of this is being able to access domain data like employees from all the applications. So per example to get employees data, I use the method `example.com/Entities/WebServices/EmployeeWs.asmx/GetAll`

When I try to get employees data from my localhost with JQuery.Ajax, it works fine on IE8. But when using Firefox, the $.ajax call sends me to the success function but with an empty message (also checked the response from firebug and it is a 200 OK - 0byte)

I have put the jQuery.support.cors = true; but it does not help in Firefox or chrome.

I have also tried to publish the test app in `example.com/TestProject` but the result is the same. It only works in IE.

does anybody know what could be the cause of the error?

Using IE8, Firefox 8.0.1, Chrome 11.0.6.  JQuery 1.7.1

Thanks in advance.

```
var requestedUrl = "http://example.com/Entities/WebServices/EmployeeWs.asmx/GetAll";

jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: requestedUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success:

    function(result) {

        alert("ok. " + result);

    },

    error:

    function(xhr) {

        alert("err. " + xhr.responseText);

    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

The ports/protocols are the same? You can have this error if you call http://example.com from https://example.com for instance.

Edit: have a look there. I did not test it myself. [How do jQuery do its cross-domain ajax calls and how can I replicate em with mootools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726704/how-do-jquery-do-its-cross-domain-ajax-calls-and-how-can-i-replicate-em-with-moo)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the http protocol, but each web application resides in an specific port and application in the same server. If I don't use the jQurey.support.cors=true statement, I get a cross-domain error also in IE. But putting it I get it right in explorer and no errors in Firefox, but also not returned data.

Comment: I think your problem comes from that then. If each app is on a different port, it's considered as an other domain.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is supposed to work if I use the jQuery.support.cors = true, isn't it?. An also in IE it is working, and I receive no error in any browser, just not receiving data.

Comment: The whole point of CORS is to allow for cross domain requests, hence his original question.