# Jquery json error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am facing a problem when returning json from a domain.

In one file i have the following

```
var postData ="domain=testing.gr";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: postData,
    beforeSend: function(x) {
        if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
            x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
    url: 'http://www.ewebs.gr/advprodigy/adv.php',
    success: function(data) {
        // 'data' is a JSON object which we can access directly.
        // Evaluate the data.success member and do something appropriate...
        if (data.success == true){
            $('#keimeno').html(data.message);
        }
        else{
            $('#keimeno').html(data.message);
        }
    }
});
```

...and in the PHP file I have hardcoded the following:

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json');

    $domain = $_POST['domain'];

    // Set up associative array
    $data = array('success'=> true,'message'=>'Success message: hooray!');

    // JSON encode and send back to the server
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Yet i get an error on returning.. response is empty!
http://prntscr.com/x333k

Comment: are you doing cross domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to have this on the server:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you did not got `json` from your `server` so try this,

```
<?php 
    //header('content-type: application/json');

    //$domain = $_POST['domain'];

    // Set up associative array
    $data = array('success'=> true,'message'=>'Success message: hooray!');

    // JSON encode and send back to the server
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

If this works then add this `error_reporting(-1);` to your `php file` to get `error`.

Also read this for `header json` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file

Comment: First, thank you for the quick answer.. second.. it didnt work.. still empty response...

Comment: I am assuming that your page is on same `domain`. Is is correct?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638773/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726704/how-do-jquery-do-its-cross-domain-ajax-calls-and-how-can-i-replicate-em-with-moo

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
{
type: "POST",
contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType : "json",...}
```